# Octopus Deploy's Permissions for Web Site Files

Tags: iis, permissions, application-pool, octopus-deploy

I have several ASP.NET Core Web API services that are deployed via Octopus Deploy (v2019.12.1) to IIS.

I am trying to figure out how the permissions work to the files.  When I look at the files/folders, they do not have any any permissions setup on them to allow the App Pool to access them.  I don't understand how this works.  But I did not care until today when stopped working.

I setup a file share to the `Applications` folder under the `Octopus2` directory.  When I did that it all stopped working.  My sites now give me an error saying that they do not have permissions to access the config file.

When I look up fixes for this, they say I need to add the App Pool to the file/folder security.  When I do this it works... until the next deploy when octopus makes another folder that does not have the added permissions.  I could move those permissions up a folder, but then I am moving to manually managing it.

And somehow it worked without giving the App Pool direct permissions.  So here is my question:

**For an Octopus Deploy IIS Web Application, how does the application have access to the config file?**  (Assuming you did not do anything beyond the basic template for an IIS Web Application (and supplying a user for the App Pool).

Comment: It depend on what kind of config file. If application require to access config file, we need to grant permission to application pool. In some case, configuration file like redirection.config is not loaded by application pool identity but authenticated user. So I'm used to set authentication user to edit authentication credential to "application pool identity". Process monitor could help you view what permission are required on your IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using the custom installation folder where I'm keeping all my applications.

**D:\Applications**

- D:\Applications\Product\Services\App1
- D:\Applications\Product\Services\App2

Before any deployment I have a step (required step) in order to set up root home directory as above.

[Create Folder step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nANh.png)

I'm granting all IIS application's identities ability to access their installation folder. 
In case you are using Octopus installation directory you can create child step which will grant desired permission to your application identity.

Application directory:

```
Octopus.Action.Package.InstallationDirectoryPath
```

[Octopus System Variables](https://octopus.com/docs/projects/variables/system-variables)